# About class composition

Tags: c++, oop

I am making a little system for controlling network packets. I have the following classes:

- Packets (have functions for retrieve and set data)
- AuthPackets (inherit the packets class)
- AuthSend    (send functions for AuthPackets)
- AuthRecv    (recv functions for AuthPackets)

So according to what i understand AuthSend and AuthRecv are a composition of AuthPackets, but they both need the Packets class for functionality.

So the code looks like this:

```
class Stream {
private:
    int position;
    void* packet;
    void* get_streampointer();
    public:
        void Skip(int bytes);
        void NewPos(int pos);

        void SetShort(short Data);
        void SetInt(int Data);
        void SetStringRef(StringRef* stringref);

        short GetShort();
        int   GetInt();
        void GetStringRef(StringRef* storedata);
};

class Packets : public Stream {
public:
    void PacketEncrypt();
    void PacketDecrypt();
    short Size;
    short Type;
};

class AuthPackets: public Packets {
    AuthSend send;
    AuthRecv recv;
    bool Protocol(Player* player);
};

class AuthSend: public Packets {
public:
    void SecureToken(short SecurCode);
    void EncSecureToken(short SecurCode);
};

class AuthRecv: public Packets {
public:
    bool SecurCode(Player* player);
};
```

Problem is why AuthSend and AuthRecv must inherit Packets if they are a part of AuthPackets class? (which already inherit Packets).

Also if I inherit AuthPackets from AuthSend and AuthRecv I will lose the sugar syntax for calling functions like this:

```
authpackets.send.SecureToken
```

So the main question is why my design is flaw?. Thx

Comment: You're trying to make it too complicated. Also I don't see how `AuthSend` *is-a* type of Packet?!

Comment: AuthSend have functions that send packets, and i really have a lot to send, so having them in a separate class looks better than just use them inside AuthPackets. Also i can use the "authpackets.send" syntax to make it more clear.

Comment: Does the sentence, "An `AuthPackets` IS A kind of `Packets`," make sense? If not, then you shouldn't derive from `Packets` at all. It might be easier to help you if you provide some idea of what these objects do. For instance, does `Packets` have any member variables, and do you ever instantiate it? What kinds of members functions does it have? Are they all static?

Comment: Packets class is just for handling the stream data in easy way, i can set or get data from the packet. And AuthPackets ARE packets that are related to auth methods. There are a lot of auth methods divided in send and recv (packets).

Answer (score 0):

AuthSend and AuthRecv should inherit from a possibly abstract base class called Packet (note: singular). Why does your AuthPackets class include members of each type, not just common functionality? If you need a class to keep the auth packets themselves it should not inherit from Packet.

More information of what you are trying to do is required for a complete answer.

Comment: The ultimate question is if they need to inherit at all.

Comment: i update with the packet class. Is just for get data when i need it from the stream or set data in a easy way.

AuthPackets are just auth packets that i set inside a class, wich needs ofc the Packets functionality for handling them better.

I could have the AuthPackets class without the AuthSend and AuthRecv, but that would be a huge mess regarding name of functions that send or recv different packet types.

Answer (score 0):

Well I will try to give solution to ( what I believe is ) your problem here; they do need to inherit from Packets if you are using anything from what is public: in Packets in AuthSend and AuthRecv. They are not part of AuthPackets, they are just objects inside AuthPackets. You are not affecting your AuthSend and AuthRecv definitions anyway with declaring an object in another class which has the public: of Packets. I don't understand how do you mean "a flaw in design" when everything seems fine to me here if you want to use something which is public in Packets. If I'm missing give me more info about your problem here.

Comment: Problem is it doesn't seems logic to me why i need to inherit Packets in AuthSend and AuthRecv when they both are part of AuthPackets (wich already inherit Packets).

I could inherit AuthPackets from AuthSend and AuthRecv but i would loose the syntax for using functions like:

"authpackets.send.functioname" & "authpackets.recv:functioname"

Comment: How come they are part of AuthPackets?